Surge Protection Device installation and MCB
On LSP's website there's this wiring diagram for a single-phase surge protector in a sub-distribution box (Type 2). The SPD is the gray device:

Could someone explain the purpose of the MCB inside the green dotted rectangle (which I added)? To a layperson, it seems redundant. Can't we simply connect the L3 and N3 wires directly to the SPD?

It is always useful for a layperson to be informed so they can evaluate the work performed by a professional.

According to their manual, the inclusion of a second circuit breaker should be based on the national requirements.

